# Swift 5 Tabular Data framework: Importing .csv files with differing dimensions

Tags: swift, dataframe

The new TabularData framework could help me importing spreadsheet databases, but I cannot find a method in the framework that lets me export the imported data as an array without knowing the dimensions.
Until now I have been parsing such files line by line, but would like to be able to use the new method.
I can import and use the print() function from the DataFrame output, but without having a pre-existing struct to handle the different files am not sure how to make the data accessible in the app.
I have this code in a function, but cannot work out how to have it export an array.
I have been searching diligently for any hints on this, but the framework is evidently too new, and there are no examples that I could find yet on practical usage. Would be grateful any help.

```
if let testUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Timeslot template", withExtension: "csv") {
    do{
        let tsArray = try DataFrame(contentsOfCSVFile: testUrl, options: options)
        print(tsArray)
        print(tsArray.columns.count)
         colCt=tsArray.columns.count
         rowCt=tsArray.columns.count
        
    } catch {
        print(error)
       
    }
}
```

Comment: "...export the imported data as an array without knowing the dimensions."
 You can find the dimensions using `tsArray.shape.rows` and `tsArray.shape.columns`.

Comment: yes, I looked at this... but my problem is not being able to return an array from a func without having a pre-existing struct apparently...
But I am pretty new to programming and I may well be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Let me suppose that I have a csv file such that it has the following data.

> firstname,lastname,month,year
>
> jim,gordon,6,1972
>
> carry,adams,8,1990
>
> nancy,johnson,3,1985

Then I can read data and put them in a struct model as follows.

```
import UIKit
import TabularData

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func loginTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Mine", ofType: "csv") else {
            print("Path cannot be parsed")
            return
        }
        
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        let data = try! DataFrame.init(contentsOfCSVFile: url)
                
        var persons = [Person]()
        for row in data.rows {
            guard let first = row[row.startIndex] as? String else {
                print("ouch")
                return
            }
            guard let last = row[row.startIndex + 1] as? String else {
                print("ouch")
                return
            }
            guard let month = row[row.startIndex + 2] as? Int else {
                print("ouch")
                return
            }
            guard let year = row[row.startIndex + 3] as? Int else {
                print("ouch")
                return
            }
            
            let person = Person(first: first, last: last, month: month, year: year)
            persons.append(person)
        }
        for person in persons {
            print("first: \(person.first) last: \(person.last) month: \(person.month) year: \(person.year)")
        }
    }
}

struct Person {
    let first: String
    let last: String
    let month: Int
    let year: Int
}
```

And the last print call generates the following.

> first: jim last: gordon month: 6 year: 1972
>
> first: carry last: adams month: 8 year: 1990
>
> first: nancy last: johnson month: 3 year: 1985

Comment: thanks... but this is not the answer because it involves hard programming a struct and I need to be able to handle different array dimensions. 
(The input data is all strings and not enormous, but tends to change every day)
I am looking for some way of grabbing the array readout at loading to feed into the app.